# how do I access the bottom of the List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to figure out how to remove the last GameObject that entered the List. Currently this code has allowed me to "Remove" GameObjects in the order that they were "Add" to the list but id like to instead remove the last one added.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour

List<GameObject> stock = new List<GameObject>();
List<GameObject> waitingRoom = new List<GameObject>();


public void PayStock()
{
 GameObject topCard = stock[0];
    
    stock.Remove(topCard);
    waitingRoom.Add(topCard);
}
```

Comment: `stock[stock.Length - 1]`will do - or `stock[^1]`

Comment: Entering those have given me errors. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Oh, sorry,, it should be: `stock[stock.Count - 1]` `List` does not have a Length property.

Comment: I have actually tried this line of code before but when testing it, it seems to sort the list before adding or removing which is not what I want. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You can also use `stock.Last()` to get the last element.

Comment: stock.Last( ) gives me this error which im not sure what it means.
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'List<GameObject>' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no accessible extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'List<GameObject>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @CodingNewbie `stock.Last()` gives you that error because you need `using System.Linq;` for it, but you shouldn't use it. Just use `stock[stock.Count - 1]` or `stock[^1]`, it'll be much faster. Also, neither `stock[stock.Count - 1]` nor `stock[^1]` do any sorting at all.

Answer (score 4):

I guess [Stack collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) fits your needs, you described typical LIFO

Use `Push` to add item and `Pop` to remove last item from collection (you will also get that item as returned value).
So your code will look like:

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour

Stack<GameObject> stock = new Stack<GameObject>();
List<GameObject> waitingRoom = new List<GameObject>();


public void PayStock()
{
   GameObject topCard = stock.Pop();
   waitingRoom.Add(topCard);
}
```

If you want to use List you can get last element like:

```cs
GameObject topCard = stock[stock.Length-1];
// Or in C# 8.0+
// GameObject topCard = stock[^1];
// Or using System.Linq
// GameObject topCard = stock.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Linq` library provides useful extensions to control lists. For example, simply use Last() in your question.

```
using System.Linq;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<GameObject> stock = new List<GameObject>();
    List<GameObject> waitingRoom = new List<GameObject>();
    
    public void PayStock()
    {
        var topCard = stock.Last();
    
        stock.Remove(topCard);
        
        waitingRoom.Add(topCard);
    }
}
```